# Scale d3 x axis(time) to zero

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am making a chart using d3 and time data.
However, its scale is wrong.
It is a simple example.

Code is below:

```
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
width = svg.attr("width"),
height = +svg.attr("height") - margin.top - margin.bottom,
g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%H:%M:%S");

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
  d.date = parseTime(d.date);
  d.close = +parseFloat(d.close);
  return d;
}, function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.close; }));

  g.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x))
    .select(".domain");

  g.append("g")
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .append("text")
      .attr("fill", "#000")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("dy", "0.71em")
      .attr("y",2)
      .attr("text-anchor", "end");

  g.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-linecap", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", line);
});
```

Data is:

```
date,close
00:00:00,0.00
03:00:00,10
06:00:00,20
09:00:00,30
12:00:00,40
15:00:00,50
18:00:00,60
21:00:00,70
```

The point midnight,0 is wrong. It should be at 0,0.
Instead, it generates this:

[image]

How can it fit the chart correctly (starting at 0,0)?

Link to the Codepen:
https://codepen.io/jaqueline-passos/pen/mGpexG/

Comment: a demo of the script would help troubleshoot

Comment: Here it is: https://codepen.io/jaqueline-passos/pen/mGpexG/

Comment: your codepen is not the same as the example posted. the codepen contains multiple x-axis, y-axis, paths and 00:00 is at the y-axis crossing. How you can draw a line with one (1) point is a riddle to me.

Comment: @riov8 it is the same, except for the way the data is loaded. D3 generates the y values. In my computer is exactly the same. Dont worry about that. The x is the one that matters. Midinight should be at 0,0. It is at 0,3 or something like that... not at 0,0...

Comment: **It is NOT the same**. place a `console.log` and you will see

Comment: @rioV8 The general logic of the code is exactly the same, she's just swapping `d3.csv` for a `csvParse`.

Comment: @JaquelinePassos first of all you don't need that `for` loop in your Codepen, you're appending the same line and axes several times. But the most important is this: the issue here is not reproducible. I'm getting midnight from 1900 as the first tick, which is expected. If I use `utcParse` I get the first tick at 11am, which is also the expected result since I live in Australia. But neither `timeParse` nor `utcParse` gives me the result in your image. Are you running the code in São Paulo? (just to get the information about the timezone).

Comment: @GerardoFurtado see OP's location -- yes.

Comment: Yes, I am. When I use utcParse, the first readable tick is 9pm... @GerardoFurtado, in your chart midnight is at 0 in the y axis?

Comment: @JaquelinePassos Yes, it is, the axis starts precisely at 12AM, 1900. Here is a snapshot, I'm using `tickFormat` to show the ticks as hours: https://snag.gy/mCq2i0.jpg. Other than that, it's exactly your same code.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado: you say the code is the same but with a difference: so it is not the same.

Comment: @rioV8 I believe my point is perfectly clear.

Comment: The difference in the code is irrelevant, just like your comment... @rioV8 It gives 0 help to solve the problem.